# Trying to have header and unordered list on same line

Tags: html, css, header, html-lists

I feel like an idiot asking this and I've scoured the internet looking for some answer and didn't seem to find anything.

All I'm trying to do is have my header element and my unordered list on the same line without cancelling the specific margins both of them contain.

```css
h3 {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
}

ul {
  text-align: right;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 id="header"> Darius Spady </h3>
  <ul>
    <li> About </li>
    <li> Projects </li>
    <li> Contact </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You probably didn't find anything specific as the primary issue has to do with the fundamentals of element display; block vs inline. `h3`, `ul`, `li` are block level elements, they will always take up the full width of it's parent element. Because of this they'll always start on a new line (below previous element). Based on your use of `text-align` it looks like you'd want to learn about `floats` and/or `flexbox` to properly align those elements to the left and right side of the page (containing element).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would introduce a parent element and use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` to put them on the same line, separated by the available white space. You can use `align-items` to vertically align them as well.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<header class="flex">
  <h3 id="header"> Darius Spady </h3>
  <ul>
    <li> About </li>
    <li> Projects </li>
    <li> Contact </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is one of those I know the answer is simple but I can't figure it out lol Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using Bootstrap and will be really simple to accomplish what you need.

```
<!-- Using Bootstrap -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Darius Spady</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">About</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Projects</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

or you can use tables so don't need to play with styles...

```
<!-- HTML only -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3>Darius Spady</h3>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li> About </li>
                        <li> Projects </li>
                        <li> Contact </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```