# how to align title and unordered list on same line

Tags: html, css

[image]

here im having portfolio as h1 and navbar links as unordered list. But how can i place those items exactly at indicated position? exactly inline with portfolio title? Please help me

```css
  #navbar h3
    {
        color: gold;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    #navbar ul li
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        
        margin-right: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    
        
    }
    #navbar ul li a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    #list
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        float: left;
        
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
```

```html
    <nav id="navbar" >
                    <h3>PORTFOLIO</h3>
                    <ul id="list">
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
    
                </nav>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to have header and unordered list on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963187/trying-to-have-header-and-unordered-list-on-same-line)

Comment: #1 but, can i have title in centre? coz if i follow that it goes to left by itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for this:

```css
#navbar
{
   display: flex;
}
#navbar h3
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    #navbar ul li
    {
      display: flex;
        list-style-type: none;
        align-self: center;
        
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 0 5px;
        
        border-radius: 15px;
    
        
    }
    #navbar ul li a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    #list
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        float: left;
        
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
```

```html
   <nav id="navbar" >
                    <h3>PORTFOLIO</h3>
                    <ul id="list">
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
    
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#navbar h3 {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
  color: gold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#navbar div,
h3,
ul {
  width: 33.33%;
}

#list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
#navbar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
#navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
 <nav id="navbar">
      <div></div>
      <h3>PORTFOLIO</h3>
      <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

I add a new empty div to your HTML code to make this task a little easy, hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

**I think this should solve your problem :**

> PS: flex box it may not be useful in this case.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  position: absolute ;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right:40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar" >
    <h3>PORTFOLIO</h3>
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```